# Handling Concurrent Updates in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

I'm currently working on a project that involves a CnosDB database, and I'm facing challenges related to concurrent updates. The scenario is as follows: multiple users can simultaneously update rows in a table, leading to potential conflicts and race conditions.

I've heard about concepts like transactions and locks but I'm not sure about the best practices to handle concurrent updates in CnosDB effectively. Could you provide guidance on how to manage and mitigate issues related to concurrent updates in a CnosDB database? Are there specific strategies or features in CnosDB that can help in such scenarios?

Thank you for your insights!